# Efficiently checking if a polytope has more than $N$ lattice points in its relative interior.

Tags: polytopes

Let $P$ be a polytope in $\Bbb Q^d$. I am curious if there is an efficient way to check if $P$ has more than one integral point in its relative interior.

More generally, is there an efficient way to check if $P$ has more than $N$ integral points in its relative interior?

Comment: Only the face-representation or vertex-representation of the polytope is known? Also, is it a full-dimensional polytope?

Comment: @ABBalbuena Let's say that the vertices are known and that it is not necessarily full-dimensional.